# how does this circuit works

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I think I understand left side of the circuit. It is a 2 stages amplifier with positive feedback via C2 and R3, but it's still strange to see how Mk1 and R1 are connected. normally, shouldn't the resistor be connected on the top? and also, what does C3 really doing?

R7 and C4 are used to limit the noise from the right side of the circuit to the left? isn't C4 too large? Will 10uf more than enough?

The right side is very complex. I don't get it at all. it seems like a multivibrator circuit, but it just looks weird. any explanation?

Comment: Maybe a link to where you uncovered it would yield some better answers.

Comment: Its got a nasty DC biasing arrangement for Q1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either Q3 or Q4 will be on. Whichever is on will have a low collector voltage, which will cause the top of C5 or C6 to be low (via the 10k resistors from the collectors). When Q2's collector makes a negative going transition, C5 or C6 will take the base of whichever transistor was on to a negative potential, causing that transistor to turn off and allowing the other to turn on. Once one transistor turns off, the cross coupling resistors (R10 and R11) will keep the other one on.

So each time Q2 collector goes low, Q3 and Q4 swap over.

Comment: Let us assume that Q4 turns on first. then Top of C6 is 0 volt and bottom is 5v (what happen to C5? which state is it in?). When Q2 going transition, There will be a 0 volt on the bottom of C5. (5v-5v=0 volt, so 0-5=-5V on the top of C5), which will turn off Q4; which will turn on Q3. When Q3 is on, top of C5 is 0V and bottom is 5V!! And the purpose of D1 and D2 is to block positive voltage from R9, R8, R12, R13 into getting to the base of both transistor? C5 and C6 are used to store the states and to black dc from R6?

Comment: @Atmega328 yes that is correct, you have a good understanding of the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be a clap-switch, you clap and the light toggles ?

Mk1 and R1: Indeed microphone to ground and R1 to supply is more usual but that does not mean this does not work. For the microphone it does not matter, it just needs a biasing voltage, which is has. And it will modulate that biasing current with the incoming audio.

C3 looks to me like a low-pass filter in combination with R4

Yes R7 and C4 are supply filtering for the microphone amplifier. C4 is large but it just depends on what suppression you want at certain low frequencies. 10 uF or 47 uF, it will not make much difference.

The right side is indeed somethink "multi" but there are no capacitors inside the circuit itself. C5 and C6 only couple the microphone amplifier to this circuit. C5 and C6 are not part of the circuit itself. So it's not multivibrator.

It's a flip-flop, it has two states: Q3 conducts and Q4 does not or the reverse: Q4 conducts and Q3 does not. When Q4 conducts the LED lights up.
Switching between the two states is done through C5 and C6. If the line to the microphone amplifier is pulled low, the flip-flop changes state.

Comment: C3 is there to bias that second NPN into either saturation or cutoff (when Q1 turns on sufficiently Q2 turns off abruptly and visa versa). R5 limits the base current to a reasonable level. R4 is for the Q1 amplifier load as well as to pull up Q2 to be normally on.

Comment: A flip-flop is sometimes called a "bistable multivibrator", as an obvious extension to "astable multivibrator" and "monostable multivibrator". No "internal capacitors" are needed for the bistable type.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter wheter you connect the microphone on the top or the bottom for it to work. However, as it roughly behaves as a "capacitor", you get a low voltage on the signal pin when you connect the resistor as in your circuit, which might come in handy when it is not high pass filtered. However, here it is high pass filtered by C1.

Then R4 and C3 form a low pass filter to the signal.

The circuit to the right is called a (sequential switching) Bistable Multivibrator. 
It is basically a circuit that toggles the output whenever a (negative) pulse is seen on the input.

[image]

You can find some information about bistable multivibrators (flipflops) [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/bistable.html).

R7 is indeed pretty large. However, for a stable power supply I would keep the capacitor C4 large enough. Especially with a large resistor in the power supply path.